# Node.js with PHP-Codeigniter and MongoDB

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

I have an architecture question and I would love to hear your opinions.

We have HTML game that we used PHP-Codeigniter/MySQL to develop it. We want to add realtime multiplayer mode in the game, so we chose node.js to develop that module. Also, we decided to change MySQL to MongoDB.

My question is: Node.js module will need to get and set data to the database. Would it be better for node.js to access the (MongoDB) database directly or to access the data through PHP code and have all the DataAccess functionality to be held in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a personal choice, and there isn't enough information on your two implementations to know what they might usefully share.

Assuming you already have game logic in the PHP/CodeIgniter backend *and* this backend is already using MongoDB, I think it would be more sensible to consolidate the data access in PHP and add a RESTful API for your frontend to call. Supporting multiple implementations of the same logic can add unnecessary maintenance overhead and subtle bugs.

However, if the Node.js multiplayer implementation is mostly independent of the PHP/CodeIgniter backend (i.e. the multiplayer features use MongoDB, but the PHP version uses MySQL) it would probably be cleaner for the Node.js backend to talk to MongoDB directly.